# Is it possible to programmatically set value for p-calendar angular component from outside app via pure js

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I want to create a browser extension that would fill form on site, that are using angular. While I can fill text inputs and then trigger validation by emitting `input` and `blur` events, I have problem with `p-calendar` component: it empties value after `blur` event. I didn't find better way than simulate user's clicks on pop-up for selecting time, but it doesn't work (you can test it on [calendar showcase](https://primeng.org/calendar))

```
    const calTimeInput = // select input with time;
    calTimeInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));
    const hourPickerButtonUp = document.querySelector(".p-hour-picker > button");
    
    hourPickerButtonUp.click(); // doesn't work
    hourPickerButtonUp.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); // doesn't work
```